# Blender final render changes at last frame?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm not very experienced with 3D, only just starting out, so please bear with me.
I'm trying to render a scene for some 3D examples we need for work, and I'm trying to render the scene in Cycles, but something gets messed up at the last frame of rendering. While the scene is rendering just fine, it'll then switch to a weird foggy not-so-good-res render of the same scene. 

[image: rendering just fine...]
[image: final tile]
[image: and then this.]

Any help with fixing this would be greatly appreciated :) I'm pretty sure I've done something wrong but I don't know what, or where to find it!

Thank you

Comment: I really don't know what that is or how to fix it; but is it crucial to have that last frame in there? Deleting the frame might be a better approach. Hope you figure out what's the matter, and welcome to Blender.StackExchange!

Comment: Do you have nodes used to composite scene (or you can show `Node Editor` contents)? As it seems to be, you get that result at the last moment of rendering frame (when compositing will be proceeded, if it is present in scene), but not at the last frame.

Comment: The image looks like a *Mist Pass* (*Render Layers > Passes*). Your compositing could be doing this, could you please show the compositing setup (if any)?